# Is there a way to use the Node.js oracledb library without editing my PATH variable?

Tags: node.js, express, node-oracledb

I am trying to build a web interface with Node.js to show data from an Oracle database at work. I did some research and found that I will need oracledb to be able to access it. Any installation guide I find says I need to edit my PATH variable to use it.

I don't have admin rights to my work pc, so is there any way around this? Is there a way maybe to make a temp PATH for one instance of the command line I am running? Any work around is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update* With node-oracledb 6 you no longer need the Oracle Client libraries.  By default the driver is a pure JavaScript implementation.  You don't need to change PATH. See the [release announcement](https://medium.com/@sharad-chandran/usher-in-a-new-era-with-the-node-oracledb-6-0-pure-javascript-thin-driver-e10e2af693b2).

With node-oracledb 5 on Windows and macOS you can set the location of the Oracle Client libraries by calling `initOracleClient()` without needing to do any external configuration.  This is all [documented](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-node-oracledb-thick-mode-on-windows):

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
try {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: 'C:\\oracle\\instantclient_19_6'});
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Whoops!');
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
}
```

There is only one [installation guide](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-node-js-and-node-oracledb-on-microsoft-windows).  Did you have difficulty finding it?  Do you have any suggestions for improvements?

Comment: Than you very much. I have seen this page but I guess I was not understanding it correctly. I appreciate you breaking it down!